# Why Icon width is more then parent Container width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a container with IconButton inside it. Then I set width of this container to .0. I see the Icon.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget{
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: .0,
      color: Colors.black26,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Why the Icon not hide, and how can I hide the Icon then the parent Container have width = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the default `clipBehavior` of container is none.

> The [clip behavior](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/clipBehavior.html) when Container.decoration is not null.
> Defaults to Clip.none. Must be Clip.none if decoration is null.

Secondly, The default icon Size is 24. That's why you get it visible even the container size is 0.

You can change the `clipBehavior` of container.

```dart
return Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.black26,
    ),
    width: .0,
    child: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set iconSize to 0 too, like this:

```
Icon(
   Icons.info,
   size: 0,
)
```

or

```
Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
              width: .0,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Yes, but why then I set parent Containers width to 0, the Icon not shrink to zero. I use this effect in animation, so I need somehow to hide the Icon. As I can see, it's not the IconButton, but only Icon. Because it's not clickable.

Comment: I do not know the reason, but I update my answer to better solution

Comment: The reason lies on default `clipBehavior`

Comment: Thank you, I think about clipBehavior, but was confused that the Icon not clipping, not the IconButton.